# How to work out the global maximum of the likelihood of a hidden Markov model?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, hidden-markov-model

I have generated some data based on a transition matrix and emission parameters that I have set.

I want to test whether the optimisation algorithm I am using will find the global maximum of the log-likelihood, which begs the question: how do I calculate the global maximum of the log-likelihood for this generated dataset.

Suppose its a Bernoulli HMM and the data was generated from $$\Gamma = \begin{pmatrix} 0.8 & 0.2\\
0.1 & 0.9\end{pmatrix}$$ and $\mathbf{p} = (0.7, 0.3),$ how would you work out the global max?